# How to get lazy collections in spring mvc controller

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm developing application using Spring MVC + Spring Hibernate and really confused how to get lazy loaded objects in controllers. I have an entity, that have `Set` with `FetchType.Lazy` and I load it in my service. But how I understand session closed before controller was starting executing. It's possible load without `EAGER` loading?

Comment: You should explain more clearly what is the problem that you are facing.

Comment: Problem is a absence of the object when controller is executing. Because object is available in transaction only.

Comment: Ok, you have two ways to go: 1) Make `EAGER` loading 2) Make another query to get what you want.

Comment: Eager loading is the opposite of Lazy loading with the previous being loaded before a request is made while a later is loaded depending upon the request. If you are asking about Hibernate Lazy loading, you do not have to do anything at the controller.